# Validación de polígonos

Tags: javascript, google-maps

En una aplicación estoy utilizando el api de Google maps para crear polígonos en un mapa.

Muchas veces los usuarios por error crean estos polígonos solapados entre sí, haciendo que luego cause ciertos problemas para el uso de los polígonos.

Para que se entienda que quiero decir con solapados entre sí, aqui un ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para evitar la creación de estos polígonos necesito crear una función que valide que es correcto.

He intentado creando esta función pero no funciona del todo bien, porque algunos polígonos estan bien creados pero según mi funcion no lo estan:

El parametro "str" que recibe la función el la propiedad geometry que viene de los polígonos creados con Google maps, por ejemplo:

```
"{\"rings\":[[[-69.93660755753615,18.514164481329143],[-69.9367503251965,18.514369114975647],[-69.93648382556384,18.514564230778124],[-69.93632202221545,18.514312007911506],[-69.93661231645815,18.514159722407133],[-69.93660755753615,18.514164481329143]]],\"spatialReference\":{\"wkid\":4326}}"
```

Aqui la función:

```
isValidPolygon(str) {
  
    const polygon = JSON.parse(str);
    const rings = polygon.rings;

    if(!rings){
        return false
    }

    console.log(rings)

    // Verificar que se proporcionaron al menos tres coordenadas
    for (let i = 0; i < rings.length; i++) {
      if (rings[i].length < 3) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    // Verificar que las aristas no se solapen
    for (let i = 0; i < rings.length; i++) {
      const coords = rings[i];
      for (let j = 0; j < coords.length - 1; j++) {
        for (let k = j + 1; k < coords.length; k++) {
          if (
            coords[j][0] === coords[k][0] &&
            coords[j][1] === coords[k][1]
          ) {
            return false;
          }
        }
  }
}

// Si no se cumplen las dos condiciones anteriores, el polígono es válido
return true;
```

},

Answer (score 3):

Pude resolverlo utilizando el paquete [polygon-selfintersect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polygon-selfintersect)

La función quedo asi:

```
    isValidPolygon(geofence) {

    const geometry = geofence.geometry;

    const polygon = JSON.parse(geometry);
    const coordinates = polygon.rings;

    if(!coordinates){
      return false;
    }

    if( validPolygon.findSelfIntersections( coordinates[0] ) ){
      return false;
    }

    return true;

},
```